# backbone.js route not working

Tags: javascript, apache, backbone.js, routes

I've defined

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "photos/": "showPhotos",
      "pic/:object_id": "getPic"
      //"*actions": "defaultRoute"
    },

    showPhotos: function() {
      console.log("routing: showPhotosPage");
      App.showPhotosPage();
    },
```

I also made sure to initiate and start the router...

```
  // Initiate the router
  var app_router = new AppRouter();

  // Start Backbone history
  Backbone.history.start();
```

When I point my browser to localhost/~myusername, the get the page and scripts to load (by looking at firebug).    But if I point my browser to localhost/~myusername/photos/photos/, I get the browser error below.

Not Found
The requested URL /~jayc707/moments/ was not found on this server.

I'm running Mountain Lion with Apache.

Thanks!

Comment: try localhost/~myusername/#/photos

Comment: Works!   Thanks.   How should I modify my routes such that localhost/~myusername/photos works?

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to.

Comment: Use `pushState: true` in `Backbone.history.start` call (http://backbonejs.org/#History-start)  Beware that initial request would be served by web server when user reloads the page, so make sure it returns something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Layoric mentioned in the question comments, by default Backbone.Router understands `#` URLs, so the url would look something like `/~jayc707/#/moments/`

It is possible, however, to use standard urls such as `/~jayc707/moments/` with Backbone's `pushState` support as explained in the [Backbone.Histrory documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Using pushState has its pros and cons. The major downside is, that older browsers do not support it, and older browsers will degrade to hash-based URLs. Another is , that you have to configure your web server (Apache) to returns your root page for any URL relative to it. See the documentation above for more info.